# How to change mileage representation forms in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, data-conversion

I would like to change the manner in which the mileage is represented in the database. For example, right now the mileage is represented as 080+0.348; this would mean that this particular feature is at mileage point 80.348 along the roadway corridor. I would like to have the data represented in the database in the latter form, 80.348 and so on. This would save me from having to export the dataset to excel for the conversion. Is this even possible? The name of the column is NRLG_MILEPOINT.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the current datatype for NRLG_MILEPOINT?

Comment: I don't know that right off the top of my head. Im at home now so I can't look at the database right now. But since it has both numbers and characters i would imagine that it would have been assigned to varchars(255). I like the idea of adding a column for that converted representation. I could just change the select statement to include that column instead. The main reason I need to convert it so that I can use it as a join with another table to sift out the data i want. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could try is to pick the string value apart into its component pieces and then recombine them as a number. If your data is in a table called TEST you might do something like the following:

```
select miles, fraction,
       nvl(to_number(miles), 0) + nvl(to_number(fraction), 0) as milepoint
  from (select regexp_substr(nrlg_milepoint, '[0-9]*') as miles,
               regexp_substr(nrlg_milepoint, '[+-][0-9.]*') as fraction
          from test);
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e77bf/1).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: In 11g or later I would be tempted to build this conversions as a virtual column.  [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#sthref5130)

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have done the trick! So im pretty new to sql, if i wanted to include these new milages as a part of the original table would i put the above query into a subquery for the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer provided above, I was able to expand it to get exactly the answer i needed. Thanks a ton to everyone who helped! Here is the query i ended up with:

```
    select distinct nrlg_dept_route,corridor_code_rb,nrlg_county,next_county,
    nvl(to_number(miles), 0) + nvl(to_number(fraction), 0) as milepoint
    from (select regexp_substr(nrlg_milepoint, '[0-9]*') as miles,
        nrlg_milepoint as nrlg_mile_point 
        nrlg_dept_route as nrlg_dept_route,
        nrlg_county as nrlg_county,
        next_county as next_county,
        corridor_code_rb as corridor_code_rb,
        corridor_code as corridor_code,
        regexp_substr(nrlg_milepoint, '[+-][0-9.]*') as fraction
        from corridor_county_intersect,south_van_data_view)
        where nrlg_dept_route = corridor_code
        order by 1,5;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to do this.  Which one depends on your situation, how the data needs to be stored, and how it is being interacted with.  Some of these options include:

1. Changing the datatype.

This option would potentially require you to change how the data is being stored currently.  The conversion of the data would have to be done by whatever is writing the data to the schema currently.

2. Creating another column that stores the data in the correct format.

If you have an existing means of storing the data that would be broken by changing the datatype of NRLG_MILEPOINT and/or you have a requirement to store the data in that format; you could optionally add another column... say NRLG_MILEAGE_DISPLAY that is of a [datatype number](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313) perhaps, and store the data there.  You could make a trigger that updates/inserts NRLG_MILEAGE_DISPLAY appropriately, based on the data in NRLG_MILEPOINT.

3. If you are just wanting the data to be displayed differently in your select statement, you can convert the datatype in your SQL statement.  Specifically how you would do this depends on the current datatype of NRLG_MILEPOINT.

Assuming that varchar2 is the type, based on the comments, here is an [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/956df/7) link displaying a crude example of option 3.  Your usage of this may vary depending on the actual datatype of NRLG_MILEPOINT.  Regardless of its datatype... I am sure there is a means of converting how it is displayed in your query.  You could take this further and create a view if you needed to.  As an inline view or as a stored view, you can then use the converted value for doing your join later.

Comment: I just need the data to be exported with the correct output. The reason for the conversion is for a join with another table so I can use matching milage as a way to parse out the data i need. The data then would be used in ArcGIS as a single geodatabase.

Comment: i'll get back to this in the morning! Have a nice night!

Comment: Typically you should do option 3 above (convert the data type using SQL). Most databases, especially a robust one like Oracle, have plenty of functions to easily convert from one data type to another, and will do so much easier and faster than using Excel to do it.

One valid reason to change the data type in the database is if the same column is stored in multiple places in the database in different data types and you change the data type(s) to standardize on the same one.

Comment: I definitely agree with @MikeJones.  The ordering of the options isn't really ranked or anything...just how they came to mind.  It really doesn't sound like you need to create another column, or change your datatype; but depending on the details of your situation... those are, as previously stated, options.